# How to stylize paper-card with :hover, :active states

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

Polymer elements add some cool material design to the web page. While using polymer, I was not able to add :hover or :focus or such selectors to the paper-card element.

```
<style is="custom-style">
    paper-card{
        min-width: 33vw;

        --paper-card: {
             background-color: transparent;
         };

        --paper-card-header: {
             background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
         }

        --paper-card-content: {
             background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
         };
    }

    paper-card:hover{
        --paper-card-content: {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
         };
    }
</style>
```

The above :hover selection failed to work. 
[Check this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HUgJ4Tx4hDOo1tPhqDwy?p=preview)

There exists other polymer elements like paper-button where the :hover states work properly. Is there any other proper way to apply :selectors to polymer mixins?

How do I make a :hover selection? Is there any workaround for this issue? (Would be better if only in CSS without JS)

Answer (score 0):

for example you can do this

```
--paper-card:hover {
         background-color: transparent;
     };
```

or

```
--paper-card: {
         background-color: transparent;
         transition: color 2s;
     };
paper-card:hover {
    color: red;
}
```